# Evaluating convolution $f\star g:=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\chi_{[-c,c]}(x-y)\chi_{[0,\infty]}(y)e^{-y} d\lambda_d(y)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

$f(x)=\chi_{[-c,c]}(x), c>0$

$g(x)=\chi_{[0,\infty)}(x)e^{-x}$

where $\chi$ denotes the indicator function.

I want to determine the convolution $f\star g:=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\chi_{[-c,c]}(x-y)\chi_{[0,\infty]}(y)e^{-y} d\lambda_d(y)$

I looked at both indicator functions:

$\chi_{[-c,c]}(x-y)=\chi_{[x-c,x+c]}(y)$ and

$\chi_{[0,\infty)}(y)$

So if I didn't make any mistake the integrand $\chi_{[-c,c]}(x-y)\chi_{[0,\infty]}(y)e^{-y}\neq0 \Leftrightarrow y \in [\max(x-c,0),x+c]$.

Then $f \star g=\int_{\max(x-c,0)}^{x+c}e^{-y}dy$ and otherwise $f\star g=0$

Is that correct? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Well what about values of $x$ and $c$ such that $x+c<0$? The convolution would certainly be $0$.

Otherwise, this looks right to me. We have that $\chi_{[-c,c]}(x-y)=1$ iff $-c\leq x-y\leq c$ (or $\ x-c\leq y\leq x+c$). Let $M=\mathrm{max}\{0,x-c\}$. Given that we don't have the situation mentioned above, taking $M$ as the lower bound guarantees that $\chi_{[0,\infty]}(y)=1$ for $y\in [M,x+c]$.